# How can I package a WebWorker for use in a portable library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, web-worker

I have a library package that provides some hooks which in turn do some expensive calculation on worker threads:

```
// example/App.tsx

import {useFancyPants} from '@fancy-pants/hooks';

  ...
  useFancyPants("kittens"); // Help! I need to call a worker thread
  ...
```

```
// fancy-pants/src/hooks.ts

export function useFancyPants() {
   const worker = new Worker(new URL('../worker/fancy.ts', import.meta.url));
   worker.sendMessage(...);
   worker.onMessage(...);
}
```

```
// fancy-pants/src/worker/fancy.ts

self.onMessage(...);
```

```
// fancy-pants/src/index.tsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Demo from './Demo';

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```
// fancy-pants/src/Demo.tsx
Demo.tsx

import {useFancyPants} from './hooks'

  ...
  useFancyPants("rainbows")
  ...
```

```
// fancy-pants/webpack.config.js

const path = require("path")

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/Demo.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "fancy.js",
        path: path.join(__dirname, "./dist/"),
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"],
        modules: ["node_modules"]
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["babel-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: ["ts-loader"],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Inside `fancy-pants`, the `Demo` app works correctly. Webpack compiles the worker `fancy-pants/worker/fancy.ts` to `fancy-pants/dist/src_worker_fancy.worker.js`, where it's available to the `new Worker(new URL('../worker/fancy.ts', import.meta.url));` code (even though it's not in the `fancy-pants/public/` folder ... this is a deeper magic I don't understand). There's a bit more config required to wire all this together but I'm trying to keep this example as simple as possible.

What is the best way to make the `useFancyPants` hook work from a *different* package, i.e. `example/App.tsx`? I.e., when I import and use `useFancyPants` inside my `example` app, how does it bundle and then talk to a worker thread? Ideally I would prefer not to have to manually compile and save the `fancy-pants` worker to `example/public`, though I suppose that's an option. (Note that I'm in a monorepo, if that helps, though ideally I would like `fancy-pants` to be a package importable and usable from anywhere.)